# How to write criteria Query with multiple Or condition for a subdocument in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, java-8, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, criteria

I am trying to write a criteria query for document which contains subdocument in it. And I want to query on both the items of the document and the subdocuments with some and as well as multiple or conditions. Below is my document strucutre

```
public class ParentEntity {
@Id
private String id;
private String sName;
private String itemDesc;
private String localTimeStamp;
private boolean isStatus;
private List<ChildEntity> childEntity;
private List<String> itemList;
}   

public class ChildEntity{

private String prc;
private LocalDate effDate;
}
```

Now I want to query on a condition which will satisfy the below condition

1. We will fetch if isStatus is true
2. We will fetch if effDate is today.
3. We will fetch if localTimeStamp= null or localTimeStamp is empty or localTimeStamp field does not exists in mongoDb collection

   ```
   so in one expression  the condition is 1 and (2 or 3)
   ```

Below is my code what i have done

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
Query query = new Query();
criteria.add("isStatus").is(true);
criteria.andOperator(criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("childentity.effDate").is(LocalDate.now),Criteria.where("localTimeStamp").is("");
query.addCriteria(criteria);
List<ParentEntity> list = mongoTemplate.find(query,ParentEntity.class);
```

This is giving me result  while the isStatus is true and effDate is today and localTimeStamp is "" , but i want to check also the localTimeStamp=null and localTimeStamp filed does not exists in the document.

How I will include 3 or s in a single condition with one and operator ?
Someone help me , i am new in mongoDb.

Comment: would the comparable SQL statement look like ... 'SELECT * FROM ParentEntity WHERE isStatus = true AND effDate = TODAY() AND (localTimeStamp = null OR localTimeStamp = "")'?  What does empty string mean?  And why are you using a string for a timestamp?

Comment: @barrypicker the timestamp is coming as string and the sql conditions what you wrote is the correct representation

Answer (score 0):

I suggest investigating [spring-boot-starter-data-search](https://github.com/commerce-io/spring-boot-starter-data-search).

- add the starter to your pom file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>app.commerce-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-search-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

- enable the Search Repository:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = SearchRepositoryImpl.class)
public class MyConfiguration {
}
```

- make your repository extends `SearchRepository`

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends SearchRepository<UserDocument, String> {
}
```

- use this repository to get your data

```java
String search = "address.name: myName or email: myEmail and (address.country: FR and address.city: Paris)";
Page<UserDocument> result = userRepository.findAll(search, pageable);
```

You can find a demo for MongoDB [here](https://github.com/commerce-io/spring-boot-starter-data-search-mongodb-demo)

---

*Disclaimer: I'm a contributor of spring-boot-starter-data-search*